# oracle sql - replace value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select name,count(case),starttime, endtime 
from employee 
where team in  ('dba','spt','sd') and name in 
(('dba1','db2','db3','spt1','spt2','sd1','sd2') 
and starttime between sysdate - 3 and sysdate ;
```

when i ran this query i am getting below output, where the user spt1 doesnt have any data for last three days so its not coming up in the result

```
dba1 12 23 42
dba2 14 12 15
dba3 23 11 23
spt2 53 23 43
sd1  40 34 23
sd2  98 34 23
```

but i need to get the result as below

```
dba1 12 23 42
dba2 14 12 15
dba3 23 11 23
spt1 -  -  -
spt2 53 23 43
sd1  40 34 23
sd2  98 34 23
```

is there any method to get this result?

Comment: First of all, show your table structure and  your real query. This one is invalid for oracle (COUNT + other fields in the SELECT clause, and no GROUP BY), and also not logical if working with time fields.

Comment: @sabarinahtan . . . Your starttimes and endtimes look like numbers, not date/times.  The comparison to `sysdate` would not seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using the below query

```
   WITH data AS
    (
             SELECT   name,
                      count(
                      CASE),
                      starttime,
                      endtime
             FROM     employee
             WHERE    team IN ('dba',
                               'spt',
                               'sd')
             AND      name IN ('dba1',
                               'db2',
                               'db3',
                               'spt1',
                               'spt2',
                               'sd1',
                               'sd2')
             AND      starttime BETWEEN SYSDATE - 3 AND      SYSDATE
             GROUP BY name,
                      starttime,
                      endtime)
    SELECT *
    FROM   data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name,
           '-',
           '-',
           '-'
    FROM   employee em
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS
           (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM   data dt
                  WHERE  dt.name=em.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join`:

```
select n.name, count(e.case), e.starttime, e.endtime 
from (select 'dba1' as name from dual union all
      select 'db2' from dual union all
      select 'db3' from dual union all
      select 'spt1' from dual union all
      select 'spt2' from dual union all
      select 'sd1' from dual union all
      select 'sd2' from dual
     ) n left join
     employee e
     on e.name = t.name and
        e.team in  ('dba','spt','sd') and 
        e.starttime between sysdate - 3 and sysdate
group by n.name, e.starttime, e.endtime ;
```

Note:  This returns the missing values as `NULL` rather than `'-'`.  `NULL` is definitely the more typical way to do this in SQL.  You can convert the values to a string, but I would recommend sticking with `NULL`.